# BIRT vertical text in excel output

Tags: java, excel, pdf, report, birt

I would like to make vertical text in excel output. I am currently using BIRT 4.2.2 with nativexls. I pasted vertical text as .svg image into table header cell but the output looks strange. There is an image with no border around the cell. Is there another way to accomplish this?

output:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIabe.png)

Comment: I am not familiar with BIRT or nativexls, but Excel has built-in functionality to have text in a column display vertically, by going to Formatting --> Alignment. Is that something that will give you what you want? Could you post a screenshot of what you're expecting?

Comment: @Zack question updated. I would like to have borders around that picture but birt didnt print it.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I'm not familiar with BIRT or nativexls, but you can quite easily specify that a cell has vertical alignment in Excel itself.

On the Cell Formatting screen, set the Alignment to 90 degrees:
[image]

This will give you the result you need:
[image]

Again, I'm not familiar with the other technologies you're using, so my apologies if this is not helpful (i.e., if you can't adjust the formatting from your workflow). Of course, if you're working with the raw Excel file, you should be update to update the XML files contained within the XLSX container to use the formatting you need.